# Multiprocessing prime number check exhibits weird behavior

Tags: python-3.x, optimization, generator, python-multiprocessing

I have the following parallelized code that checks if a number is a prime number.

```py
import math
from multiprocessing import Pool, Manager
import time
from itertools import product

SERIAL_CHECK_CUTOFF = 21
CHECK_EVERY = 1000
FLAG_CLEAR = b'0'
FLAG_SET = b'1'
print("CHECK_EVERY", CHECK_EVERY)

def create_range(from_i, to_i, nbr_processes):
    if from_i == to_i:
        return from_i
    else:
        nbr_ranges = []
        count = from_i

        while(count < to_i + 1):
            nbr_ranges.append(count)
            count+=1
            
        k, m = divmod(len(nbr_ranges), nbr_processes)
        subranges = list((nbr_ranges[i*k+min(i, m):(i+1)*k+min(i+1, m)] for i in range(nbr_processes)))
        subranges = [arr[::len(arr) - 1] if len(arr) > 1 else arr for arr in subranges]
        return subranges


def check_prime_in_range(n_from_i_to_i, value):

    (n, _range) = n_from_i_to_i
    if len(_range) > 1:
        (from_i, to_i) = _range
    else:
        return True

    if n % 2 == 0:
        return False

    # check at every 1000 iterations.
    # At every check, see if value.value has been set to FLAG_SET
    # If so, exit the search.
    # If in the search a process finds the factor, set the flag and exit the process.
    # NOTE: check_every flag is suboptimal
    check_every = CHECK_EVERY

    for i in range(from_i, math.floor(to_i), 2):
        check_every = -1
        if not check_every:
            if value.value == FLAG_SET:
                return False
            check_every = CHECK_EVERY

        if n % i == 0:
            value.value = FLAG_SET
            return False

    return True


def check_prime(n, nbr_processes, value):

    # serial check to quickly check for small factors. if none are found, then a
    # parallel search is started
    from_i = 3
    to_i = SERIAL_CHECK_CUTOFF
    value.value = FLAG_CLEAR

    if not check_prime_in_range((n, (from_i, to_i)), value):
        print("Found small non-prime factor")
        return False

    # continue to check for larger factors in parallel
    from_i = to_i
    to_i = int(math.sqrt(n)) + 1
    ranges_to_check = create_range(from_i, to_i, nbr_processes)
    ranges_to_check = zip(len(ranges_to_check) * [n], ranges_to_check)

    with Pool() as pool:
        args = ((arg, value) for arg in product(list(ranges_to_check)))
        # print(list(args)) # comment out this line and the code breaks
        results = pool.map(check_prime_in_range, args)

    if False in results:
        return False

    return True

if __name__ == "__main__":

    start = time.time()
    nbr_processes = 4
    manager = Manager()
    value = manager.Value(b'c', FLAG_CLEAR) # 1-byte character 
    
    n = 98_823_199_699_242_79
    isprime = check_prime(n, nbr_processes, value)
    end = time.time()

    if isprime:
        print(f"{n} is a prime number")
    else:
        print(f"{n} is not a prime number")

    print(f"Duration: {end - start}s")
```

`check_prime()` finds a range of factors and tries to determine if there is a non-prime factor. Each range is sent to a process to find a non-prime factor. A `multiprocessing.Manager` object is used as a flag, so that if a process found a non-prime factor, it sets a flag. The flag is checked periodically. If the flag is set, all processes are terminated.

Because `multiprocessing.map` only accepts function with one argument, I used `itertools.product` to create an argument generator that contains the range and the manager object.

If I run the code as it is, I get the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/briansia/projects/python/multiprocess/prime_manager.py", line 118, in <module>
    isprime = check_prime(n, nbr_processes, value)
  File "/home/briansia/projects/python/multiprocess/prime_manager.py", line 103, in check_prime
    results = pool.map(check_prime_in_range, list(args))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 367, in map
    return self._map_async(func, iterable, mapstar, chunksize).get()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 774, in get
    raise self._value
TypeError: check_prime_in_range() missing 1 required positional argument: 'value'
```

If I print the args generator above the `map` function, then the code runs correctly. How exactly did the print statement modify the generator such that it works with the `map` function?

Answer (score 1):

To illustrate the problem, change the `with Pool()` block in your program to this:

```
with Pool() as pool:
    args = ((arg, value) for arg in product(list(ranges_to_check)))
    x = list(args)
    # print(x)
    results = pool.map(check_prime_in_range, x)
```

This will always crash whether you comment out the print statement or not.

The print statement in your code is not the issue: it is `list(args)`, which causes the generator expression to run.  Generator expressions run once and once only.  After you've done `list(args)`, the generator still exists and it's still named `args`, but it is now exhausted.  When you run your program with the line containing `list(args)`, you have already used up the generator; therefore you effectively pass an empty iterator to Pool.map.  Your program doesn't actually work.  It doesn't produce a traceback because it doesn't really do anything.

The problem with your code is this function:

```
def check_prime_in_range(n_from_i_to_i, value)
```

It takes two arguments.  The first time you call it, you indeed pass two arguments:

```
if not check_prime_in_range((n, (from_i, to_i)), value):
```

But when you call it indirectly through Pool.map, it is called with only one argument.  As you stated yourself, Pool.map only passes a single argument to its function.  It's true that your generator has made two objects into a tuple, but that tuple is only one object and therefore it's the only argument that gets passed to `check_prime_in_range`.  There is no second argument, as the traceback indicates.

I don't know how you want to fix the problem, but it might be a good idea to define `check_prime_in_range` as a function of one argument, and call it consistently.  You can unpack the single argument inside the function, for example:

```
def check_prime_in_range(x):
    n_from_i_to_i, value = x
    (n, _range) = n_from_i_to_i
    # etc.
```

Your first call would now be:

```
if not check_prime_in_range(((n, (from_i, to_i)), value)):
```

That's rather clumsy so I would consider defining a little class to hold all the variables in a single object.  But that's a style issue.